# How to cancel HttpListenerContext.AcceptWebSocketAsync?

Tags: c#, .net, http, websocket

It does not have a cancellation token parameter. Also HttpListenerContext does not have related (Begin/End)AcceptWebSocket methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe the following solution fits better in your case, which is based on this [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/10/05/how-do-i-cancel-non-cancelable-async-operations/).

This will stop listening as soon as the cancellation token is triggert, then you are able to implement the custom logic to cancel the operation. In my case its enough to break the loop, but it can really be anything you want.

```
    public void Stop()
    {
        this.Status = ServerStatus.Stopping;

        this.listener.Stop();
        this.cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();

        this.Status = ServerStatus.Stopped;
    }

    private async void ListenForConnections(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        try
        {
            while (this.Status == ServerStatus.Running)
            {
                var socketTask = this.listener.AcceptSocketAsync();

                var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
                using (cancellationToken.Register(s => ((TaskCompletionSource<bool>)s).TrySetResult(true), tcs))
                {
                    if (socketTask != await Task.WhenAny(socketTask, tcs.Task).ConfigureAwait(false))
                        break;
                }

                var context = new TcpContext(socketTask.Result);

                this.OnConnectionReceived(context);
            }
        }
        catch (ObjectDisposedException)
        {
            // Closed
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is there any way to avoid the `ObjectDisposedException`? I've been looking around for a proper way to avoid this exception but it seems like everyone just eats it and moves on.

Comment: Its currently not possible, but there is an issue here to track the request https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/5749

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm, you get context from `HttpListener` which is listening to requests (the context does not listen itself, it only wraps requests/responses for you as far as I understand). I guess you should call [`HttpListener.Stop()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener.stop(v=vs.110).aspx) Will it do the trick?

Comment: Looks like the answer. I need some time to check this one.

Comment: @DenisGladkiy sure thing, if possible please comment on the matter when you check it. I based my assumption purely on documentation, my experience with `HttpListener` and common sense ^-^ It would be nice to know if it's the right way (I didn't work with web sockets).

Comment: According to web sockets RFC the only thing that AcceptSocketAsync should do is to send several HTTP headers: "ok, let's talk via WebSocket from now". I've dug the sources of the HttpListener and AcceptSocketAsync is doing exactly this. Looks like poor API design: internally there is only one async call and it has an overload with cancellation token :(

Comment: I've failed to reproduce the exact case of the blocking on this "send" operation: even if the client is not reading from the socket, the server has a buffer large enough to accept the headers. So I can't guarantee that closing HttpListenerContext will do the stuff. But source code from MS and common sense say that this is the way to go. I've tried to call HttpListenerContext.Response.Close(); before calling the AcceptWebSocketAsync: as expected ObjectDisposedException from the AcceptWebSocketAsync.

Comment: In my case canceling is needed to shutdown the application. So I will vote your answer up. But I need time to play around with Ronald's second answer, to see if it fits the general case: closing is not the canceling and it will not allow the future work. To mark your answer as accepted I need to fix the question.

Comment: @DenisGladkiy Ronald's answer is actually the same as mine but with a nice code snippet that adds cancellation (he's calling `this.listener.Stop()` which is exactly what I advice)

Answer (score 1):

The best you can do is wrap the listening part in a thread and when you want to cancel execute Abort on the thread.

Be sure to catch the ObjectDisposedException that can happen in the method.
Did the same thing for the lower level TcpListener.

```
    public void Stop()
    {
        this.Status = ServerStatus.Stopping;
        this.listener.Stop();

        this.listeningThread.Abort();

        this.Status = ServerStatus.Stopped;
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Listens for connections.
    /// </summary>
    private async void ListenForConnections()
    {
        try
        {
            while (this.Status == ServerStatus.Running)
            {
                var socket = await this.listener.AcceptSocketAsync();
                var context = new TcpContext(socket);

                this.OnConnectionReceived(context);
            }
        }
        catch (ObjectDisposedException)
        {
            // Closed
        }
    }
```

Comment: The design you offer is not applicable to the web sockets, I think :( In your case, you can create a single accepting thread. But the web socket is an abstraction over HTTP connection (over TCP socket): by the time I have a HttpListenerContext the TCP connection is already created and "AcceptWebSocketAsync" is actually do a handshake over HTTP, so it can't be offloaded to a thread (a thread per client is not scalable).

Answer (score 0):

All I was looking for was a way to make sure that AcceptWebSocketAsync won't get hung forever by negotiating with a hostile remote who blocks my listening threads.  I'm new to Task and await/async, but this seems to do what I want:

```
CancellationTokenSource upgradeTimeout = new CancellationTokenSource(1000);
HttpListenerWebSocketContext webSocketContext = await Task.Run(async () => { return await httpContext.AcceptWebSocketAsync(null); }, upgradeTimeout.Token);
```

Is there anything wrong with doing it this way?

Thanks